# The destructor in a class keeps calling it's self when using the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm running this code:

```py
import random
class Pound:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value=1.00
        self.color="gold"
        self.num_ages=1
        self.diameter=22.5
        self.thickness=3.15
        self.heads=True
        self.num_pocket=10

    def __del__(self):
        print("Coin spent!")

    def rust(self):
        self.color="greenish"

    def clean(self):
        self.color="clean"

    def flip(self):
        heads_options=[True,False]
        choice=random.choice(heads_options)
        self.heads=choice

coin1=Pound()
print(coin1.value)
```

When I run it in the Python IDLE I have no issues whatsoever. But when I run it in ATOM (using the atom-python-run or the script package) it always shows me this output:

```
1.0
Coin spent!
```

The destructor seems to call itself. I have no clue how to solve the issues and I haven't found anything asked about this anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code, when interpreted as a script, the object goes out of scope right after `print` since after that, the program ends. `__del__` is called in that case because at that point, "the instance is about to be destroyed" ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)).

When run from a REPL though (like IDLE), it doesn't go out of scope until you kill the REPL, so `__del__` isn't called right away.

This is the expected behavior.

---

Also note, the docs don't prefer the word "destructor":

> This is also called a finalizer or (improperly) a destructor.

Comment: I don't really understand what I'm supposed to do at this point. I want to keep using ATOM, so how could I change the code so that it works?

Comment: @lynyx Why are you using `__del__` in the first place? For what purpose?

Comment: If I ever want to destroy the object I'm using. i just got into oop so I don't really know what to say...

Comment: @lynyx Python is garbage collected, so objects are automatically destroyed when they go out of scope. You don't need to do anything manually. It's highly unlikely that you need `__del__`. If you showed your actual use case, I could give a better suggestion. The code you posted is too contrived for me to be able to tell what you're trying to do though.

Comment: I'll just stick to not using it. Thanks!